# aggregate method, $match property throwing syntax error

Tags: mongodb

[image]I am learning mongodb. I am trying aggregate method with $match property but it is not working for me
 My collection has 3 documents only as follows:

1. {name: "Priya", age: 26}
2. {name:"Shreya"}
3. {name: anuj}

When I execute this query :

```
 db.collections1.aggregate([ 
{ $match: { "name": "Payal" }}
 ]);
```

Output is: Syntax error

I am not able to find the error

I also tried it as:

```
db.collections1.aggregate([ 
{ $match: { "age": 26 }}
 ]);
```

same error

Comment: Your syntax is correct. There must be something else around your query that causes this issue. Which client/driver are you using? Which line/column does it complain about?

Comment: Changed the image specifying line/column number

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, couldn't see the image - it's blocked here at work.

Comment: I am using online terminal : https://www.jdoodle.com/online-mongodb-terminal. It is showing error at $match

Comment: It would appear your online terminal is broken. This is not a mongodb problem. Use the real product and not somebodies website.